# Html data attribute in Coldfusion form submission

Tags: html, coldfusion, custom-data-attribute

I understand how to pull out the data attribute in JQuery from an HTML form, but can it be done from within a .cfc controller to which a form is passed?

**Page.cfm**

```
<cfform action="controller.cfc" method="getData">
    <cfinput name="uploadMyData" type="submit" data-primaryID="123">
</cfform>
```

**Controller.cfc**

```
function getData(rc){
    writeDump(rc.uploadMyData.?????(primaryId)????);
}
```

Not sure if the data attribute is stored in any way in the struct. 
I tried a getMetaData on the rc.uploadMyData but just got a list of java functions.

**Update**

[Adrian J. Moreno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047/adrian-j-moreno)

> Data attributes are just markup that impact the internal data object of the element. They are not part of a form request. You wouldn't submit a form to a CFC file either. Using Ajax, you can read the value from the data attribute and pass it to the server as part of the request's data packet.

So in **Page.cfm**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var otherData = $("#myForm").serialize();
    function sendForm(){
        var primaryID = $("#submitData").data("primaryID");
        jQuery.post("urlpath/controller/",'{"id":'+''+primaryID+'}', function(dataReturn, status){
            //I want to get my form and submit the other data as well to the controller
        }            
    }
</script>

<form id="myForm" action="sendForm()">
        <input name="uploadMyData" id="submitData" type="submit" data-primaryID="123">
        <input name="importantThing" value="#importantVariable#" type="text">
</form>
```

> pass it to the server as part of the request's data packet.

how would I pass them together?
I want this form submission to redirect to another page so I don't see how I couldn't use the controller? The form data should go the newPage.cfc to process it and get it ready for output on newPage.cfm. I'm using framework one but that doesn't change much.

Thanks for the help, what do you think?

**Update 2**

Ok, now I ask myself why I would want to submit a form with both ajax and coldfusion form submission together? I realize that's not what should be done. I can either

1. Submit the form via JQuery/Ajax with no page reload, and include the data attribute in the post url and include the serialized form data

**Page.cfm**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var otherData = $("#myForm").serialize();
    function sendForm(){
        var primaryID = $("#submitData").data("primaryID");
        jQuery.post("controller/method/?primaryId="+primaryID+"",otherData, function(dataReturn, status){
            //do stuff with dataReturn or do a javascript redirect
        }            
    }
</script>
```

**Controller.cfc**

```
function method(requestContext){
    //do stuff with that otherData, all stored in request context. includes the primaryID value i appended to the url
    //send it back to the Page.cfm
    fw.renderData("rawjson",jsonString,200,"");
}
```

and if that made it back ok, I could run a function back in my original view with that information. Like display it on the page.

2. Submit the form traditionally which would result in a page reload. Include a hidden input type with the value that I want to pass.

**Page.cfm**

```
<cfform action="controller.method" method="getData">
    <cfinput name="uploadMyData" type="submit" value="Submit Form Button">
    <cfinput name="primaryID" type="hidden" value="123">
</cfform>
```

**Controller.cfc**

```
function method(requestContext){
    //do stuff with requestContext.primaryID
    //go to the view method.cfm or do a fw.redirect("new page or back to the page i came from");
}
```

Why would we want to submit the form twice? just do one or the other.

Comment: Hmm... if it was value="123" then that would work. The data attribute is more of a JS/HTML thing. What happens when you dump out the form scope or meta data?  (fyi - would be rc.uploadMyData - the label "uploadMyData" would contain 123).'

Comment: Data attributes are just markup that impact the internal data object of the element. They are not part of a form request. You wouldn't submit a form to a CFC file either. Using Ajax, you can read the value from the data attribute and pass it to the server as part of the request's data packet.

Comment: Oh right Adrian - you would NOT simply submit the form scope directly to a CFC anyway. One issue above is the use of cfform - seems superflous... not really what he's aiming for.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno  I didn't want to post a long thing in the comments...so i posted an answer that I'll probably go back and edit...because it's still a question.

Comment: @MarkAKruger How would cfform be superfluous? In my understanding, yes when you want to use javascript with a form, it's easiest to use html style. So no, cfform would not be "what I'm aiming for" in that respect. Correct?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Why not submit to a cfc? In the context of [framework one](https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/wiki#user-content-adding-a-controller) when i submit a form with action="place/item" it goes first to place.cfc and looks for the method item, then goes to my views/place/item.cfm. Is that not the purpose of the controller? Process data in between page navigation? If I am not grounded in some good basic principles I am open to doing more research on my own, I just don't get enough information from your responses on what I should be getting here that I'm not. Much appreciated though

Comment: @KevinB When I have a form with
`<input name="myinput" type="hidden" value="#var#">`
Then when I submit that form, I should be able to access rc.myinput which will give me the "var" value. Correct? But I don't want to show that input element in the form. So yes, to my understanding, hidden input is a thing. Again if I'm out there I'm all ears. I don't understand the comment completely. Thanks again.

Comment: If it's hidden, it won't shown... what are you saying? My point is if you want to pass extra data along with a form that is being submitted through the ordinary submit event (not ajax), it must be an input with a name and a value. data attributes don't get passed.

Comment: @KevinB Alright I understand that much. So what I'm seeing here is that the ajax and "traditional" form submission methods cannot/should not be used together.

Comment: correct. One will abort the other. You could use ajax and then redirect in the success, but... that's not really a great idea, as it results in two trips to the server instead of one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117959/discussion-between-matt-wilde-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt, I think you're confused about a number of things that are quite basic to HTML, JavaScript and jQuery and have nothing to do with ColdFusion.

Let's start with an [HTML Form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

`<form id="{{unique_dom_value}}" action="{{uri}}" method="{{http_verb}}">`

1. **unique_dom_value**: Some string unique to the document. Allows you to reference the entire form object using JavaScript.
2. **uri**: The URI to which you submit the form for processing.
3. **http_verb**: Defaults to `GET`, but you should most often use `POST`.

The URI you're trying to post to in just `controller.cfc`, but that won't do anything but redirect you to the ColdFusion CFC inspector.

In the context of most MVC frameworks, `index.cfm?event=handler.action` uses the underlying framework to call a function named `action` within a CFC named `handler`. Without a framework, you have to do that manually. So if you have a CFC named `controller.cfc` and want to send your form data to a function named `myFunction`, you need to say `action="controller.cfc?method=myFunction`.

But that's not right either. When you submit a form, the browser expects to load the URI that's found in the `action` attribute. But your CFC function doesn't respond with HTML, it responds with something else. Maybe a query object, maybe JSON. This is why you would use [jQuery.Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the form data (including the data attribute values) to the CFC's function, which should return data in JSON. Once you get a response, you can continue processing on the same page or redirect to another page.

However, since you're using Framework One, I would look into the documentation on using `renderData()` within one of your handler functions.

Comment: I edited my answer with "**Update 2**" trying to put your suggestions to use